# VBScript to stop service works in WinXP not in Win7

Tags: vbscript, windows-7

I have a boot script that copies some ini files, based on the OS being used, for MySQL Server.  The script works fine on WinXP but in Win7 it does not stop the service.  No error is reported.  The script appears to run fine except for the fact that the ini files are not copied if the service is running.

I have removed the stop service portion of the code and placed it in a script by itself.  However, it still works on WinXP and not on Win7.

Can anyone see any reason for the script not working?

```
Sub StopService(computerName, serviceName)
Dim service

Set service = GetService(computerName, serviceName)
If(service Is Nothing) Then
    Call Log.Warning("The " & serviceName & " service on the " & computerName & " computer was not found")
Else
    service.StopService()
End If
End Sub


Function GetService(computerName, serviceName)
Dim wmiService, objectsList, eObjectsList, ObjService, item, sysID

Set wmiService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & computerName & "\root\cimv2")
Set objectsList = wmiService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Service Where Name = '" & serviceName & "'")
For Each ObjService in objectsList  
    If(ObjService.Name = serviceName) Then
        Set GetService = ObjService
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
Set GetService = Nothing
End Function


StopService ".", "MySQL56"
```

Thanks for any and all help,

Charles

Comment: Starting and stopping a services requires admin privileges.  You don't have them in Win7, you must start your script from an elevated command prompt.  Right-click the shortcut and select Run as Administrator for example.

Comment: Script files, such as .vbs and .js, do not have the 'Run as Administrator' option.  Not on my Win7 anyway.

Comment: That's why I recommended starting them from the elevated command prompt.

Comment: Maybe I'm looking too far ahead.  I will put the boot script in the local computer group policy so maybe there is a way to make that setting there.  Thanks for your help.